# AppStore: Where to select which version to use from TestFlight when publishing an app?

Tags: ios, app-store

(See edit below) I have multiple builds in TestFlight. Now I want to release the last one to AppStore. Where do I select it? All I can see is this:

[image]

**EDIT**

I found out that when I released 1.0, Apple actually released one of the old builds instead of the last one (How is this even possible?! I submitted the app to review 2 days after last build was uploaded to TestFlight). So now the question is how I can apply the last build?

Here is the All Builds tab:
[image]

And here is the Build section for release 1.0 (nevermind release 1.1, I made it by mistake and can't find any option to delete it) :
[image]

Comment: Is it sure that builds for version **1.1** exist on TestFlight ?

Comment: There should be al little + next to build. So it seems like you do not have an build for this bundle ID.

Comment: Ok, on [TestFlight I have only builds for version 1.0](https://i.imgur.com/tKqVpGW.png). But then why was not the last version selected when I sent 1.0 to review? And how can I now activate the last build?

Comment: after a version has become available, you will see a blue ⨁ symbol right next to the word "Build", until then you could follow the status of your uploaded version under the "TestFlight" tab; __in practice:__ after you uploaded a version it takes about 20-25 minutes before it appears on your console as available, but you will be notified about that via email as well.

Comment: @holex, it's been days since the last build was uploaded to TestFlight.  [I cannot see](https://i.imgur.com/dP8XS7B.png)  any button to add new build.   If I go to All Builds [I can see the last build](https://i.imgur.com/kO3GKRq.png) but no way to enable it.

Comment: @PrimožKralj, are you seeing the new build under the "TestFlight" tab? if not, upload it again; as I said, 20-25 minutes; if that takes longer, you can just repeat the procedure in an hour time without any issue – but be aware of the version number in the bundle should (=must) match as well, otherwise you will not see the desired build _for_ the current version (1.1).

Comment: @holex Yes, the last build was uploaded a few days before I even submitted the app (1.0) into review. The thing is that I am not the developer so I can't fiddle with these builds. I am just the owner of the app.

Comment: @PrimožKralj, that is strange, if you are just the owner... should not the developer manage the entire procedure of publishing the app...? it seems that I spoil my own client only... anyhow, the point is, you need to ask your dev to upload the build again with the correct version number (1.1) again, because they might have not done it at all... :/ that could be the current case, based on your screenshot: no build for version 1.1, only for 1.0 – you cannot publish that as 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possibility which exists is that there are no builds available for **version 1.1**
If you check the **TestFlight** tab, there should be builds for previous versions but not for **version 1.1**

**Update** :
There are two ways you can upload the build as per your comment :
1. Change version from 1.1 to 1.0 and upload build for 1.0 There is an option to change version on itunesconnect page only.
2. From Xcode, create build for version 1.1 and upload it. Then you’ll see build on itunesconnect for 1.1 Having said that, this would skip version 1.0
But if 1.0 is your first release, you should go with option 1.

Following is the option to update the version from iTunesConnect :

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949217/appstore-where-to-select-which-version-to-use-from-testflight-when-publishing-a?noredirect=1#comment84905764_48949217)?

Comment: I know about option 2, but it will take a few more days for additional review from Apple. Option 1 I think will not work - even if the dev uploads new build for 1.0,  the original question remains: where to select it as the active build?

Comment: Both the options would work. For option 1, you just need to update the version on itunesconnect and refresh the page. You’ll see the option to add build on 1.0. For option 2, you just need to upload the build for 1.1. Remember that the build is not in review. You can change anything before you submit the build

Comment: And on your update on build not being able to delete, you cannot delete build for Ready for sale version. You can only do that if version is in a Prepare for submission stage.

Comment: Regarding option 1; I looked everywhere and can not find any option to update the version on itunesconnect. Please [check this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/EqCi0EN.jpg). Where should I look further? Thanks!

Comment: I have again updated my answer to show the option where you can update the version. And again, you are changing the version of **Ready for sale** version which is not possible. Only **Prepare for submission** version can be updated. As per your screenshot in above comment, you are trying that for Ready for sale version.